# Etymology/meaning of character 绍 and its relation to 介绍

Tags: meaning, characters, etymology

According to the dictionaries, the character 绍 means "to carry on, to continue". Looking at its etymology, I found nowhere saying nothing else from it being composed of silk (纟) and the sound 召 [zhao]. Even back in the days it had the meaning "to inherit, to carry on a tradition" and I can't see where the silk comes in.

Apart from that, where does the meaning "to carry on, to continue" relates to the word 介绍? It seems today 绍 is mostly used in the word 介绍 and in city names, like in 绍兴.

**Questions:**
1 - Why does 绍 have a silk in it?
2 - What's the meaning of 绍 in 介绍?

Thanks!

Comment: bkrs：绍：(4) 介绍, 为人引见, 使相互认识 [introduce]
绍我周王见休。 --《孟子》
胜请为绍介。 --《史记·鲁仲连传》
士为绍摈。 --《仪礼·聘礼》 
介(5) 介绍 [introduce]
其所以相亲也, 不介而自亲。 --李康《命运论》
accordingly 介绍 could be considered a 复合词 of type 联合型（并列型）（see e.g. https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%88%E6%88%90%E8%AF%8D#%E8%81%94%E5%90%88%E5%9E%8B%EF%BC%88%E5%B9%B6%E5%88%97%E5%9E%8B%EF%BC%89)

Answer (score 1):

Just my opinion after a quick look!

1 - Why does 绍 have a silk in it?

http://www.zdic.net/z/21/xs/7ECD.htm

绍: (1) (形声。从糸( mì),召声。本义:继承;紧密连续)

I would say, 糸( mì) is not really silk, just a figurative thread, band or bond.

Doesn't a thread, for example, in chinese.stackexchange.com, carry on? The idea is not new.

形声: 召声 is the sound of 绍.

2 - What's the meaning of 绍 in 介绍?

http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/4ECB.htm

介：在两者中间: 介于两者之间。between both sides (friendship)
绍: 连续 go on without stopping

introduce: the etymology is not clear, but may be:
intro- means in (between)
ducere: lead (the one to the other perhaps)

Overall: 介绍： between (2 or more people) tie a bond which (hopefully) lasts.